# How do I attach two hot wires to a single terminal?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I've got a hot wire in two wires out for two rooms. The two wires aren't sitting right under the screw in the switch and I believe it's fried the switch.

It's been a long time since I've done any wiring but I want to think there is a simple solution for this that doesn't require feeding two wires into one screw. A different type of switch maybe?

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is called a pigtail.

Remove those two wires from the screw and with a short extra wire connect them together with a wire nut/wago.

The short wire goes to the screw and everybody lives happy ever after.

Would probably use a new switch because of the corrosion/dirt/discoloration shown.  Switches are cheap.

Can also use a better quality of switch that is made to clamp two wires under a screw.

Comment: THAT'S what I was thinking, thank you so much. I will definitely replace the switch.

Answer (score 11):

> I've got a hot wire in two wires out for two rooms. The two wires aren't sitting right under the screw in the switch and I believe it's fried the switch.

Yes, because of the horrible connection, it has suffered *series arcing*.  This has made parts very hot, could have started a fire, and certainly ruined the switch.

Replace with a **Spec Grade** ($3-4) switch.  Read the instructions and you will see they have a special procedure for getting 2 wires under each screw.  Make sure to either polish or cut back and re-strip these wires, as they are now annealed from the heat. Though you have limited length (6" in the box mandatory) so I would try to polish them up with some fine sandpaper.